# Perl Bypass 5 Seconds Waiting Page

Tags: perl, cloudflare

I'm trying to get webpage content of [webresolver.nl][1]. I've tried several codes. One of them is:

```
use warnings;
use HTTP::Cookies;
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$mech->agent_alias('Windows IE 6');
$mech->cookie_jar(HTTP::Cookies->new(autosave => 1));
$mech->add_header('Content-Type' => 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', 'Referer' => 'https://webresolver.nl');
$mech->get('https://webresolver.nl');
print $mech->content;
```

And the result is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
        <meta name="keywords" content="skype resolver, skyperesolver, free resolver api, skype, tools, resolve, resolver, database, resolvedb, ip2skype, ip to skype, ip, free, api, php, free api, web tools, advanced, webresolver, web, resolver, skype, api, skypebot, bot, 2017, 2018, leaked, whois, screenshot, website, geoip, ping, phone, lookup, number, cloudflare, working, blacklist, portscan" />
        <meta name="description" content="Webresolver.nl - Free API, Skype Resolver, Resolver, Email To Skype, Huge Database, Resolve Database, Leaked Databases">

        <meta name="twitter:card" value="summary">
        <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
        <meta property="og:title" content="Easy to use API's - Webresolver.nl" />
        <meta property="og:description" content="Webresolver.nl - Free API, Skype Resolver, Resolver, Email To Skype, Huge Database, Resolve Database, Leaked Databases" />
        <meta property="og:image" content="https://webresolver.nl/social.png" />

        <link rel="image_src" href="https://webresolver.nl/social.png" />

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="google-site-verification" content="kRHprU08vhp4g31pv2u8CsIqWZ5_XDlaou5T3P-5wv0" />
        <meta name="wot-verification" content="5e516c32e271c87e073a"/>

        <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">

        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://webresolver.nl/favicon.ico">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="https://webresolver.nl/public/images/browsericons/apple-icon-57x57.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="https://webresolver.nl/public/images/browsericons/apple-icon-60x60.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="https://webresolver.nl/public/images/browsericons/apple-icon-72x72.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="https://webresolver.nl/public/images/browsericons/apple-icon-76x76.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="https://webresolver.nl/public/images/browsericons/apple-icon-114x114.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="https://webresolver.nl/public/images/browsericons/apple-icon-120x120.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="https://webresolver.nl/public/images/browsericons/apple-icon-144x144.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="https://webresolver.nl/public/images/browsericons/apple-icon-152x152.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="https://webresolver.nl/public/images/browsericons/apple-icon-180x180.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192"  href="https://webresolver.nl/public/images/browsericons/android-icon-192x192.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="https://webresolver.nl/public/images/browsericons/favicon-32x32.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="https://webresolver.nl/public/images/browsericons/favicon-96x96.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="https://webresolver.nl/public/images/browsericons/favicon-16x16.png">
        <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#37BC9B">
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#37BC9B">
        <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="https://webresolver.nl/public/images/browsericons/ms-icon-144x144.png">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cookieconsent2/3.1.0/cookieconsent.min.css" />
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cookieconsent2/3.1.0/cookieconsent.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        window.addEventListener("load", function(){
        window.cookieconsent.initialise({
          "palette": {
            "popup": {
              "background": "#000"
            },
            "button": {
              "background": "transparent",
              "text": "#f1d600",
              "border": "#f1d600"
            }
          },
          "content": {
            "message": "By using this website, you agree that we and our partners may set cookies for purposes such as customizing content and advertising. Cookies may get shared with third-party applications for analytics and statistics.",
            "href": "https://webresolver.nl/cookie-policy"
          }
        })});
        </script>

        <title>Webresolver.nl - The best Skype Resolver</title>
</head>
<body>
        Validating browser, please wait...<br /><br />

        <i><small>If this message persists after 10 seconds, please check you have cookies and JavaScript enabled in your browser.</small></i> <br /><br />
        <i><small><small>Protection by <a href="https://webresolver.nl/">webresolver.nl</a> - Token: 5dc811c2424b9</small></small></i>

        <script>setTimeout(function() {document.cookie="WebResolverSecurityCode=bb4dfd133db6478f397a8175b9ced3b0; expires=Mon, 11 Nov 2019 00:00:00 GMT; path=/";location.href="https://webresolver.nl/";}, 500);</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I expected the webpage content is the real one (the homepage of the web), not the waiting page. I'm curious to know the code to make this work. I'm pretty new to Perl. So, if anyone can help me, i would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

That is an anti-scraping javascript snippet meant to stop people like from doing things like this.  The website will not return content until the cookie WebResolverSecurityCode is set.  All you have to do is parse the initial response to get the cookie value and set it on your $mech object.  Then re-request the page.

```
$document = q{ ... <script>setTimeout(function() {
  document.cookie="WebResolverSecurityCode=bb4dfd133db6478f397a8175b9ced3b0; 
  expires=Mon, 11 Nov 2019 00:00:00 GMT; path=/";
  location.href="https://webresolver.nl/";}, 500);</script> ... };

$cookie_value = 
  $document =~ m{\bdocument\.cookie="WebResolverSecurityCode=(\w+);} ?
  $1 : die "cookie value not found";
```

Read perlre for more information.

HTH

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried set_cookie with the cookie value. But the result still the same waiting page content.

Comment: I'll need more information to troubleshoot it any further.  Try dumping the request and response objects to make sure the cookie was set correctly.  Otherwise there could additional checks done by the website.  Try setting the browser string (user agent).